# R missing arguments in function input not matched by name

Tags: r, function, arguments, missing-data

I have a function like

```
dbh2vol <- function(dbh,hgt,...){

  if (missing(hgt)){
    hgt = 2
    cat("hgt is missing. Set to 2")
  }
  vol  = dbh * hgt
  return(vol)
}
```

if I then call it with

```
Vol = dbh2vol(dbh=10,hgt=4)
#40
```

everything is fine. If I have something like

```
Vol = dbh2vol(dbh=10,param=4)
#hgt is missing. Set to 2[1] 20
```

as expected. But if then I do

```
Vol = dbh2vol(dbh=10,h=4)
#40
```

`h=4` is interpreted as `hgt=4`. Why and how can I avoid such a behavior, that is how can the arguments be matched exactly by their names?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this... To test, I just set `hgt=2*dbh` instead of `hgt = some_other_function(dbh)` then ran `Vol = dbh2vol(dbh=10,param=4)`. The resulting `Vol` I got was `200` as would be expected if I set `hgt = 2*dbh`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the minimal example I provided. There's actually a very weird thing. By doing `Vol = dbh2vol(dbh=10,param=4)`I also get the correct result. If I change to `Vol = dbh2vol(dbh=10,h=4)` then `h` which is actually what I have in my code is recognized as if it was `hgt`. Can you check this behavior.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Same behavior if I use `hg`. It looks like if the argument name matches at least the initial part of the expected input it is not set as `missing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you observe is partial matching of named function arguments and as far as I know you can't disable it. see the r language definition for more informations https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Argument-matching

maybe it is possible for you to put the hgt argument into the three dots and check that? of course you then loose the positional matching.

```
dbh2vol <- function(dbh, ...){
  hgt <- list(...)$hgt
  if (is.null(hgt)) {
    hgt <-  sqrt(dbh)
    cat("hgt has been calculated with some_other_function")
  }
  vol = dbh * hgt
  return(vol)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with your solution, at least I know the reason for such a weird behavior.

Comment: Or just put `hgt` after `...` in the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing dbh and hgt as an argument, you can try this:

```
pars <- list(
    dbh = 10,
    h = 5
)

dbh2vol <- function(pars){
  with(pars,{
    if (!exists("hgt")){
        hgt <- 2
        cat("hgt is missing. Set to 2")
    }
    vol <- dbh * hgt
    return(vol)  
  })
}

dbh2vol(pars)
## hgt is missing. Set to 2[1] 20
```

This allows you to easily pass the parameters to other functions as well.